# All .net applications crash "stop working" after Visual Studio 2012 Express Desktop installed

Tags: windows-8, .net-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am running Windows 8 Pro x64.  Never had a problem with .net applications and I have a few I use daily for my business.

I installed Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktops.  After installing this, all .net applications (including VS) crash on startup.  They will show the UI then crash immediately saying it "stopped working", some crash after hitting a button in the UI, most crash just after the UI is loaded.

Uninstalling VS does not restore the functionality.
I disabled AV, no difference.
I used the .Net diag tool and confirmed 4.0 and 4.5 .net are installed correctly.
I did a repair on VS but no change.

Now with VS uninstalled, I am still unable to run any .net applications without crashes.

Eventlog gives me an Event ID 1000, faulting module KERNELBASE.EXE.  With no other usable details.

Comment: use WER to get crash dumps (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx). Zip and upload a few dumps

Comment: I just found something interesting.  If I log in with a different user it works.  So it appears VS 2012 Express installation corrupted my user profile some how.  I found a link from kernelbase.dll and user profile issues so I tried creating a new user.  Now if I can find a way to fix it without starting a new profile (very time consuming).

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem.

I linked it to my user profile, and eventually tracked it down to a program that was running LucidMVP. This is used to provide better performance for gamers.  Some reason when it is activated, .net applications will crash with "stopped working".  Disabling it, everything runs fine.

I contacted LucidMVP developers to let them know.